# rhc and mongo "command not found" in openShift cartridge

Tags: mongodb, shell, openshift, openshift-client-tools

My Java EE and mongo-application are up and running on openshift.
Yet since today I cannot execute neither the mongo shell nor rhc commands when logged in via SSH.

On both commands I just get 
`bash: mongo: command not found` and `bash: rhc: command not found`.

Did anything change in the last days that I just didn't get or do I have to change anything?

**Update:**
the mongo cli works when connecting through rhc portforwarding.
I filed an issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1144135

Answer (score 1):

Workaround until this is fixed:

```
export OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mongodb24/root/usr/bin
source mongodb/lib/mongodb_context 
export PATH=/opt/rh/mongodb24/root/usr/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/v8314/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/mongodb24/root/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

The rhc command is not installed on your gear, it's installed on your local machine (or should be), and you need to make sure that you have the mongodb cartridge installed on that gear (or into that scaled application) for the mongo commands to be available to you via your ssh session.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, forgot about the rhc being a remote tool.
But mongo is installed. As I said, my app is up and running.
ctl_app status also tells me 
`CLIENT_RESULT: MongoDB is running`
I just can't access it via mongo in the shell any more (it HAS been working yesterday).